# Observe to live data inside object class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I want to create a singleton object with some global variables for the whole app and also i want to observe in this object some global LiveData objects.
In one of my DAO i have a query which returns LiveData

```
@Query("SELECT * from Config LIMIT 1")
    fun get(): LiveData<Config>
```

And here is my appCommon object class

```
object appCommon {
  @Volatile
  var globalVar1: Int = 1;

  @Volatile
  var globalVar2: String = "Global value";
}
```

So my question is how to correctly declare global variable in my object class which will observe LiveData from my DAO?

Answer (score 0):

you can start observing your query in the `init` block of the object

```
object appCommon {
    val dao: ConfigDao by inject // pseudo code here, I'd go with DI 
                                 // but it's up to you how you retreive your dao 
                                 // (a repo will do better in my opinion)

    @Volatile
    var globalVar1: Int = 1;

    @Volatile
    var globalVar2: String = "Global value";

    var config: Config? = null

    init {
        dao.get().observeForever{ 
          config = it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Than'k you for answer. I have tried to realise it so but now i have another problem, can you please look on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335910/kotlin-observeforever-every-time-is-null